# Inserting a Variable into a Returned MySQL Query in PHP When Printing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a block of text with a URL in it stored in MySQL.

As an example here is the block stored in the database.  Let's say the table is called email.

```
Hi my name is john.  Visit my url: http://example.com?ID=$ID
```

Then.  In my php I have a loop looping through each person I want to send an email to.

Then I grab the email from the database:

```
$querystr = "SELECT email FROM emails WHERE ID = '1'";
$emailtext = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
$myemail = $emailtext['email'];
```

Etc.  I have the email text from the DB.

```
foreach($users as $u) {
$ID = $u->ID;

$sendemail($myemail);

}
```

So, how do I make sure that $ID variable in the original email text stored in the DB gets filled with each user's ID before I send the email?

Comment: Sure it is possible. Try it now.

Comment: Oh!  It will work just like that?  Ok, will try.

Comment: I cannot see why it would not. It should be straightforward.

Comment: Nah, it didn't work.  I re-edited the question to make it clear what I am trying to do. Hope that helps.

Comment: You have to carry out a replacement, such as `str_replace('$ID', $u->ID, $myemail)`.

Comment: Or this may also work `$sendemail(eval($myemail));`

Comment: Yeah for some reason not working.  This is the text in the DB to be replaced.  

`%theid%`

The email content once I grab it from the db is DEFINITELY $content 

I know as it is printing to email fine.  No problem.

Ths is the string replace I run right before sending the email.

`str_replace('%theid%', $theid, $content);`

But when I get the email the link shows up with this on the end:

`=%theid%` 

So, it isn't getting replaced for some reason.

Comment: Nevermind.  I forgot to re-call the variable.  i.e. $content = str_replace.  Should be good now.  Thanks much for your help.  Feel free to answer and I will upvote.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it solved. That‘s the most meaningful part. Others are not so important. :)